# What is the typeof keyword

Tags: kotlin, keyword

I couldn't find what it means in Kotlin docs nor through googling it. It certainly does exist though as IntelliJ highlights it as a keyword an [Kotlin's autogenerated keyword list file contains it too](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/descriptors/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/renderer/KeywordStringsGenerated.java#L55). I tried to figure out myself what it does but the only result I got is IntelliJ telling me `Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)`

What is it and what it does?

Comment: This might have been reserved at one time since it would be important in some dynamic platforms (i.e. KotlinJS) and instead likely was replaced with a platform specific function, such as `jsTypeOf` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/js-type-of.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the list of keywords in Kotlin at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/lexer/KtTokens.java

> ```
> // Reserved for future use: KtKeywordToken TYPEOF_KEYWORD =
> KtKeywordToken.keyword("typeof");
> ```

So this one is not used currently but might be in the future